# How to pack multiple statements

Tags: autoconf, m4

I'd like to regroup multiple statements in a `[]`:

```
AC_ARG_WITH(
    [float],
    [AS_HELP_STRING(
        [--with-float],
        [use float instead of doubles to store polynoms coefficients])],
    [real=float], <--- here I'd like to add an AC_DEFINE
    [real=double])
```

My problem is, I'm not sure of the best way to do that. I guess I can use `;`, but this does not seem really idiomatic for a `m4sh` script.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use newlines:

```
AC_ARG_WITH(
    [float],
    [AS_HELP_STRING(
        [--with-float],
        [use float instead of doubles to store polynoms coefficients])],
    [real=float]
    [AC_DEFINE....],
    [real=double])
```

It's also common to write it as:

```
 AC_ARG_WITH([
        float
        ],[
        AS_HELP_STRING(
            [--with-float],
            [use float instead of doubles to store polynoms coefficients])
        ],[
        real=float
        AC_DEFINE....
        ],[
        real=double
])
```

Comment: thanks a lot. Somehow those basic informations are hard to find on autotools.